# Redirecting subfolder to different root in NGINX gives redirect loop

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I'm trying something I thought would be fairly simple: namely, to redirect `domain.com/dashboard/` to another (different) application than my main domain, (which is a wordpress install, but that's fairly irrelevant I think).

So when visiting `domain.com/dashboard/anywhere`, this second application should act as if `/dashboard/` was the route of the domain, and process all urls etc as normal.

What I have tried so far either just causes a redirect loop, doesn't route at all or gives a 500 error.

Here's an example of my nginx location for this so far:

```
location ~ ^/dashboard/
{
   alias /srv/www/htdocs/fork/; // this is the second application I want to access

   rewrite "^(/.*)$"      http://domain.com/$1 permanent;

   index index.php index.html;

   include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

   fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
   fastcgi_index index.php;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;

   break;
}
```

I've tried switching from `alias` to `root` also, but to no avail. And I'm not really sure what to try next.

Does anyone have any idea about what could be causing the redirect? (Essentially causing a loop of `domain.com/dashboard/dashboard/dashboard` (etc).

**Update**

Okay, so following Mark's advice below, I've moved the location block above any wordpress rules, and I've commented out some code. Progress has been made in that now a request to `domain.com/dashboard/` will access the right application, but it's now looking in that application for a `dashboard` folder.

Here's the current code:

```
location ~ ^/dashboard(/)(.*)$
{
   root /srv/www/htdocs/fork/;

   break;
}
```

and the current error in the logs is `"/srv/www/htdocs/fork/dashboard/index.php" is not found` (what I'm after is it accessing `/srv/www/htdocs/fork/index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

The first time that `/dashboard/foo` gets hit, the processing gets down to the `rewrite` line, where it stops processing and redirects back to `/dashboard` on the same domain, creating a loop.

It may well be relevant that your other app is a Wordpress installation, because Wordpress includes it's own rewrite directives, which basically say that if any URL does not map to a a physical file or directory, than pass it to Wordpress. So, it's important that this bit of configuration appear before the Wordpress rewrite rules.

If I understand the situation correctly and both apps are on the same domain, you don't need the `rewrite` directive here. The `alias` directive should be sufficient to serve the `/dashboard` address from a different location.

Comment: Hey @mark yeh, you're correct both are on the same domain, I just want /dashboard/ to go to a new application. I've moved the location block above the wordpress rules and taken out the rewrite, but I'm still getting the redirect loop to dashboard/dashboard/dashboard

Comment: try commenting out the whole location block and see if you still get the error. If you do, the problem is elsewhere. If you've narrowed down to this location block for certain. Try commenting out particular lines until the behavior changes.

Comment: I've made sure the fault definitely lies within the location block, and updated above. There's some progress (it's getting to the right application), but it's checking in the wrong place. Please see above (and thanks for your help so far!)

Comment: Based on your description, it sounds like [alias](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#alias), not the `root` directive is what you want.

Comment: Added that, and now it's getting a redirect of dashboard/index.php/index.php/index.php etc (and yes, there is an index.php).

Comment: Oh, i'm also getting `directory index of "/srv/www/htdocs/fork" is forbidden`, athough the whole directory is chowned by www-data (my local nginx user). Not sure if that's the cause, or a symptom though...

Comment: That's because you have no defined index (e.g. index.php or index.html) and autoindex module is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try [alias](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#alias) instead:

```
location /dashboard {
  # you don't need regexps here, naming location will use hash lookup which is much faster
  alias /srv/www/htdocs/fork/;
}
```